# State Management - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-statements, css-grid, react-state-management

I have a three column uneven grid. I want to add this feature - Every column should have an icon to maximise it, which will make that column full screen, and then an option to minimize it should appear.

My current logic includes making a state for visibility and having a button to toggle between visible and hidden, Then conditional statement for displaying the columns if true then display if not then don't

My current code makes the content of the other columns hidden, but not the column themselves, and maximising does not happen.

How do I go about it?

Code -

```js
const [show, setShow] = useState(true)

<RiFullscreenLine color='white' onClick={() => setShow((s) => !s)} />

<div className={styles.activity} style={{ visibility: show ? "visible" : "hidden" }}>
```

Comment: It's better if you state the problem you are having with this code.  What happens if you run this code?

Comment: @vamsiampolu I have mentioned that my current code makes the content of columns hidden and not the column themselves and no maximising happens

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a simple way. You can take another that is call `isMaximized` which would be true or false.

Then in your if you are using css grid then conditionally use if true then `grid-column: 1/-1` if not then `width: 100%` should work

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you
So Basically it will go like this, right?
```const [isMaximised, setIsMaximised] = useState(false)```
and then I use the grid and width properties in a separate say .isMax div in my css file and call it in my button on onClick ?

Comment: you ca use it style tag here `<div className={styles.activity} style={{ visibility: show ? "visible" : "hidden" }}>`